# Find a cell value on another sheet with condition

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

I have Sheet2 with the value of the **Name** list, each name has 2 values for **Type A** and **Type B**.
I'd to find the value of Type A and Type B for each Name on Sheet 1. If I use VLOOKUP, I can only find 1 value of Type A. Please help.

[Demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pwPD4KC0FnmBcCnPotdSBVwyrD4UdzLl4pnfHFQD4mU/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: You mentioned Type A /B but your sheet has Type 1 / 2.  Please create a sample that accurately reflects your real data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use in B2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A&B1:C1, {Sheet2!A:A&Sheet2!C:C, Sheet2!B:B}, 2, 0)))
```

but rename Type A/B to Type 1/2

[image]

Comment: If the Name in Sheet 2 is blank, it displays many false values. Could you please help?
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pwPD4KC0FnmBcCnPotdSBVwyrD4UdzLl4pnfHFQD4mU/edit#gid=0

Comment: @JOY try: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A&B1:C1, {Sheet2!A:A&Sheet2!C:C, Sheet2!B:B}, 2, 0)))
)`

Comment: If I merged the name cells in sheet 2, the Type 2 value on Sheet 1 won't appear. Any way to solve this please?

Comment: @JOY try: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A&B1:C1, {IF(Sheet2!B:B="",, VLOOKUP(ROW(Sheet2!A:A), IF(Sheet2!A:A<>"", {ROW(Sheet2!A:A), Sheet2!A:A}), 2, 1))&Sheet2!C:C, Sheet2!B:B}, 2, 0))) )`